# Filter SQL query using several html selects in separate forms

Tags: php, post, drop-down-menu

I have several drop down menus which are static.

Upon selecting an option in either drop down a respective php variable is updated with a value.

Those php variables will ultimately be used later on in a sql query to display records based on the multiple selections.

Each dropdown is an html select contained inside its own form tags.  Forms are submitted as such

```
echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">';
echo '<select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="numberSelect" >';
```

This method is simple but does not retain the values posted from one form as soon as you submit another.

Is there a way to retain the values of multiple selects in php variables or some other method so that values from multiple forms can be used elsewhere in php?

this working snippet of php illustrates the issue,

```
<?php    
//read in selected value
$SelectedColor = $_POST['colorSelect'] ? $_POST['colorSelect'] : 'none';
$SelectedNumber = $_POST['numberSelect'] ? $_POST['numberSelect'] : 'none';

echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">'; 
echo '<label>Selected Color: </label>';
echo $SelectedColor ;
echo '<br/>';
echo '<select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="colorSelect">';
echo '<option value="none">Choose</option>';
$color_options = array('red','blue','yellow');

foreach($color_options as $option) {
$selected = ($option == $SelectedColor) ? 'SELECTED' : ''; 
echo "<option $selected value='$option'>$option</option>";
}

echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';    
?>

<br/>

<?php

$number_options = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three');

echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">'; 
echo '<label>Selected Number: </label>';
//if a number was posted get the corresponding string
echo is_numeric($SelectedNumber) ? $number_options[$SelectedNumber] : $SelectedNumber;
echo '<br/>';
echo '<select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="numberSelect" >';    
echo '<option value="none">Choose</option>';
foreach($number_options as $option => $value) {
$selected = ($value == $SelectedNumber) ? 'SELECTED' : ''; 
echo "<option $selected value='$value'>$option</option>";
}

echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: The quick solution would be to remove the ONCHANGE event from the first select, so that the entire form submits only on the 2nd select. The long solution would be to update the page with the right HTML (option remains selected) after the first selection.

Comment: Actually your code snippet looks correct

Comment: It is very close but still does not retain the value of both, for example if i select red the page reloads and `$colorSelected = 'red'` and `$numberSelected = 'none'` if i then try to select a number, `$numberSelected `gets the correct value but `$colorSelected` is reset to `'none'`

Comment: both selects should be part of the same form

Answer (score 0):

Remove first

```
</form>
```

And the 2nd

```
<form>
```

Both selects need to be part of the same form.

Comment: While that technically works it doesn't exactly answer the question

Comment: The best way would be to add a submit button at the end, and remove the onchange events. You only need to update the page if something on the page changes after the first selection.